# How to get average time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Hello everyone I have one question, I have one columns `duration` formatted time and I want to calculate the average time from the duration column, what is the excel formula?

Comment: are the cells in your screenshot formatted as text / manual inputs or are they based on some function comprising day/hour etc. formats (e.g. are these timestamps with something like the following in custom format option: *"days: "DD" hours: "HH" mins: * etc,?

Comment: the based format is general, i get with this formula =INT(F3-E3)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(F3-E3,1))&" Hour "&MINUTE(MOD(F3-E3,1))&" Minutes"
and fill F3 is "6/8/2021  20:25:18" and E3 is "6/8/2021  19:57:00" both formatted yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98XN5g4jhLwBjMipE?e=yqOthq) refer:

This depends entirely upon how the values in your screenshot have been formatted - e.g. if they are value-based (col B, below), then `average` directly should do the trick (you could format this in similar way shown):

[image: Value-based]

i.e. you could use the following function per cell A7:

```
=AVERAGE(A2:A6)
```

However, if they are string based, then some string-manipulation is required - cell C7 illustrates:

```
=AVERAGE(MID(C2:C6,1,SEARCH(" ",C2:C6))*1+1*MID(C2:C6,SEARCH(",",C2:C6)+2,SEARCH("hours",C2:C6)-10)/24+SUBSTITUTE(MID(C2:C6,SEARCH("hours",C2:C6)+6,LEN(C2:C6))," mins","")/24/60)
```

Note: cells A7 & C7 in above are themselves formatted using custom format as follows:

```
"avg: "#,##0.00
```

[image: Format for average (result cells: A8 & C8)]

Applying the same format depicted for col A values returns the following:

[image: Like-formatted output cell/duration]

Comment: but columns A is string formated no value formated

Comment: Have provided solns for both cases